# Java HTML files and JEditor Pane

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I am trying to figure out how to read an HTML file into a `JEditorPane`.

I have the following code:

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
URL helpURL = MainFrame.class.getResource("user-manual.html");
```

Now my problem is that the `user-manual.html` file needs to be in the bin folder that holds the MainFrame class otherwise it will not work. Now my problem is my directory has to look like this:

```
as1/
as1/doc/
as1/doc/user-manual.html
as1/doc/system-doc.html
as1/doc/images/
as1/src/
```

How do I go about reading the `user-manual.html` file into the URL?

Comment: where is the code where you actually add the HTML content to the pane? And what error messages are you seeing with the two answers below?

Comment: What is the output of `jar tf` on your JAR?

Answer (score 1):

The method `Class.getResource` accept also semi-relative adresses, like this:

```
 URL helpURL = MainFrame.class.getResource("/as1/doc/user-manual.html");
```

Then the path is rooted at the jar-file (or classpath directory) instead of the package directory.

Comment: It assumed that your class-files are rooted in the same directory structure, of course. Or, if you have a jar, that they are loaded from the same jar. Make sure your jar looks right.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the items directory to your classpath and continue access it as you are now or inside the directory structure as:

```
MainFrame.class.getResource("as1/doc/user-manual.html");
```

Comment: Sometimes success comes down to which class loader is used to find the resource.  As such, using an instance of a user object works where other approaches don't.  E.G. this.getClass().getResource(..) or mainFrame.getClass().getResource(..)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("as1/doc/user-manual.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons -

1. The html files might have been stored at wrong place.
2. The `setContent` method might not have been set to "text/html"